# client-side TypeScript gives error: <object>.default is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, browserify, apexcharts

My current project contains code which runs in the browser. The code is written in TypeScript and transpiled to js using this tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",                                
    "sourceMap": true,       
    "outDir": "../www/",
    "rootDirs": ["./", "../src"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true       
  },
  "files": [
    "client.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "./node_modules",
    "./node_modules/*",
    "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts",
  ]
}
```

In the code I use ApexCharts like this:

```
import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts';

[...]

deviceCard.chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector(`#${newCard.serial}chart`), options);
deviceCard.chart.render();
```

After transpiling to js with tsc, these lines become to:

```
deviceCard.chart = new apexcharts_1.default(document.querySelector(`#${newCard.serial}chart`), options);
deviceCard.chart.render();
```

since I could not figure out how to import the ApexCharts code from the node module to the browser I simply took ApexCharts from https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts, saved it to a local file and bundled everything together with browserify.

When I run it in the browser, I get an error:

> TypeError: apexcharts_1.default is not a constructor

What can I do to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

I just had to add  `"esModuleInterop": true` to my tsconfig.json, so it looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",                                
    "sourceMap": true,       
    "outDir": "../www/",
    "rootDirs": ["./", "../src"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "files": [
    "client.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "./node_modules",
    "./node_modules/*",
    "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts",
  ]
}
```